# Pass $(this) to anonymous callback function

Tags: jquery

I don't know how to pass `$(this)` to an anonymous callback function, more specifically, to the callback of the jQuery [slideTogge()](https://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) function.

Here is what I tried, but didn't work.

```
$('.target').on('click', function() {
   let self = $(this);
   $(this)
   .parent()
   .parent()
   .next()
   .slideToggle(500, function(self) {
      console.log(self); // says it's undefined
   });
});
```

Comment: $ is a jQuery function. $(this) means you called this function. Your question should be how to pass this here. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`slideToggle(500, function(self)`  means the first argument passed to this function assigning to `self`....
As the function does not return any argument so it would be undefined.

Change to:

```
$('.target').on('click', function() {
   let self = $(this);
   $(this)
   .parent()
   .parent()
   .next()
   .slideToggle(500, function() {
      console.log(self);
   });
});
```